# Python is killed - garbage collector is not called automatically

Tags: python-3.x, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Python is suddenly being Killed without any error message. As i understand this is often related to memory issues, and when i check the python garbage collector i notice that it does not clean up automatically.

In the following code i print out the default threshold for collecting garbage, load a dataset and print out the reference count.

```
import gc
from json import load as jsonload

print(gc.get_threshold())

# do something
with open(path) as f:
    dataset = jsonload(f)

print(gc.get_count())
```

Output:

(700, 10, 10)

(238, 5, 14)

As I understand the count should never be able to exceed the threshold. This is only a problem for the last "generation", the first two does never exceed this threshold. I can not even load the dataset from above, two times without python being killed. Interestingly I can load as many datasets i want if I manually collect the garbage using gc.collect() between each dataset load.

I dont know if this is related or helps, but the problem occurred after running a very large script with multiprocessing.